# MSBuild not skipping target even though no changes were made to target inputs

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, msbuild, incremental-build

I use MSBuild Version 14.0.

Following the documentation [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171483.aspx), I defined my own `Build` task like this:

```
  <Target Name="Build" 
          Inputs="@(Compile)"
          Outputs="MyLibrary.dll">

          <Csc 
              Sources="@(Compile)"
              OutputAssembly="MyLibrary.dll"/>
  </Target>
```

The idea is to reduce build time by only building incrementally -- the build task is supposed to run only when any of the files in the `@(Compile)` list (which is currently a collection of all `.cs` files in the project) is edited after the creation of the latest version of `MyLibrary.dll`.

Using MSBuild, I ran the following command:

> msbuild MyProject.csproj /t:Build /p:Platform="AnyCPU" /fileLogger
>   /flp:logfile=Output.log;verbosity:minimal

The first time I executed the command, everything was built from scratch, as expected.

However, on subsequent occasions when I ran the command again **without having made any changes to any of my `.cs` files**, the project was also built from scratch each time.

Why didn't MSBuild just skip the `Build` target even though there were no changes to any of the files included in the `Inputs` parameter to `Target`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was not working because I forgot to delete the following line from my `.csproj` file:

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildBinPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
```

So the `Build` task generated by `Microsoft.CSharp.targets` overrode the `Build` task that I had defined.

Once that line was deleted, my custom `Build` task ran as expected.

Comment: thanks for sharing your solution here, you could mark it as the answer, so it could help other community members who get the same issues.